# Rails: Validation failed Class must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add subscriptions to my product, but this doesn't work. This is my SubscriptionsController. When I use `current_user` I get the following Error: `Validation failed: Product must exist`

```
  def create
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:product_id])
    @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save!
      redirect_to product_subscriptions_subscription_path(subscription_id: @subscription.id, id: :overview)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

When I use `@product.subscriptions.build` I get the following Error: `Validation failed: User must exist`

What did I do wrong ? What should I do ?

Comment: 1. Make sure you have added the correct associations in your models - does subscription belong to user or product? 2. you write '@product.subscriptions.build' but in your create action you are creating your subscriptions from @product. Please be clearer by either explaining a bit more what you want to do or show us the code in models and controllers involved!

Comment: `@product.subscriptions.build(subscription_params.merge({user: current_user}))` should work since it appears a subscription belongs to a user and a product. Same as `current_user.subscriptions.build(subscription_params.merge({product: @product}))`